# пробелы вместо табов eslint

Tags: javascript, webstorm, eslint

Поставил проверку кода в редакторе WebStorm, eslint. Вот конфиг:

```js
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "rules": {
    "import/prefer-default-export": [0],
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": [0],
    "react/prefer-stateless-function": [1]
  },
  "globals": {
    "document": true,
    "FileReader": true,
    "FormData": true,
    "history": true,
    "location": true,
    "window": true,
  }
}
```

Теперь никак не могу убрать ошибку из кода, табы сместо пробело или наоборот, не пойму в чем дело, пробовал настраивать , гуглить. Никак не могу понять что нужно и как это убрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а чего хочется - eslint перенастроить, или код поправить? Судя по ошибке, у вас в файле испорльзуется табуляция вместе с пробелами. Попробуйте в **File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript | Tabs and Indents** отключить **Use Tab character** и отформатировать код (**Code | Reformat Code**). А еще последние версии WebStorm поддерживают ESLint auto-fix (https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/09/webstorm-2016-3-eap-163-3983/) и импорт настроек форматирования из .eslintrc (https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/06/webstorm-2017-2-eap-172-3198/)

Comment: @lena хочу поправить код, чтобы соответствовать хорошему стилю написанию кода

Comment: Можно попробовать Reformat Code в WebStorm - `Ctrl + Alt + L`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте выделить весь текст (`Ctrl+A`), нажать `Tab`, потом `Shift+Tab`

Весь код отформатируется одинаково. Чтобы такого смешения не возникало в дальнейшем, проверьте, что в настройках установлены отступы табами.